# UTF 8 support in Android as well as PHP

Tags: php, android

I am using UTF8 support to display Hindi characters in my application. But when I am doing so, I am getting this result in PHP

```
\u0939\u094d\u0926\u094b\u0926\
```

while I am getting the correct Hindi letters in Android. My issue is that I want to show hindi characters in both Android app as well as PHP web page.

I have used this line in PHP file which is giving Hindi character in Android

```
$row = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Please suggest some changes in the below given PHP code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/php; charset=utf-8');
mysql_connect("host","root","pwd");
mysql_select_db("db_name");

$row = mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

$sql=mysql_query("select * from t1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC Limit 50");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
$output[]=$row;
}

$countries = array('countries' => $output);

echo json_encode($countries);
  mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Just a note: Your content type should be `application/json` not `text/php`

Comment: @MichaelHelwig No, it should be `application/json`

Comment: Yes, corrected my comment :)

Comment: @MichaelHelwig Thanks, but it doesnt solve my problem :(

Comment: Your json_encode result may be perfectly valid, it's just a javascript representation of utf8-encoded characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you expecting and why you are using `json_encode` if you want to display these characters in a "web page" directly. What you are seeing on your page is probably just a perfectly valid json_encoded result, so if you want to have a json_encoded representation of your result everything seems fine.

If you want to show the characters in html you can just print them out instead of using `json_encode`.

If you want to use json_encoded unicode characters in php (I think that is *not* what you are trying to achieve, but anyway...) you have to use `json_decode`, e.g. you can print out an unicode character like this:

```
echo json_decode('"\u00fc"');
```